# Does SQL write lock makes other transactions re-evaluate all queries in the tranasction

Tags: mysql, sql, database, locking, rdbms

I'm pretty new to database locking and had a basic question. My understanding is that any UPDATE statement locks the row in the table and hence, no other transaction can read/write that row. If so, consider a scenario:

Initial table: user_id = 1, count = 10

Transaction 1:
A: UPDATE table SET count = 20 WHERE user_id = 1

Transaction 2:
B. variable b = SELECT count FROM seats WHERE user_id = 1
C. UPDATE seats SET count = {b} + 1 WHERE user_id = 1

If the order of execution is: 2B - 1A - 2C, what will be result of count in the table, will it be 11 or 21?

If my understanding is correct, when 1A statement is executed, the DB puts a write lock on that row which blocks 2C's execution. Now my question is, once 1A is done,
 
will transaction 2 re-evaluate all queries(2B & 2C) in T2 related to that locked row - (which would re-evaluate the value of variable b to 20) 
OR
 only re-evaluates its blocked query(2B) - (which means variable b will still have its old value of 10)?

EDIT:
What if 2B and 2C where nested queries? Something like: 
UPDATE seats SET count = (SELECT count FROM seats WHERE user_id = 1) + 1 WHERE user_id = 1

Comment: do you have 2 or 3 transactions? with 2 that will not be possible as tranction will wait till two is finished

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's put the steps in the order you describe:

```
Transaction 2:
B. variable b = SELECT count FROM seats WHERE user_id = 1
```

Suppose `b` now has value 10.

```
Transaction 1:
A: UPDATE table SET count = 20 WHERE user_id = 1
```

This locks the row until Transaction 1 finishes.

```
Transaction 2:
C. UPDATE seats SET count = {b} + 1 WHERE user_id = 1
```

This also wants the lock that Transaction 1 holds, so Transaction 2 must wait.

```
Transaction 1:
D: COMMIT
```

Transaction 1 releases its lock when it commits.

```
Transaction 2:
C. UPDATE seats SET count = {b} + 1 WHERE user_id = 1
```

It can now go ahead, because the lock it wants is free.

The row now has value 20, since Transaction 1 committed. But the client for Transaction 2 still has value 10 in its variable `b`, so it updates the row to 10 + 1, or 11.

This overwrites the value set by Transaction 1. A third transaction may query after Transaction 1 committed and before Transaction 2 commits. Then it will read the value 20. But it will soon be overwritten as soon as Transaction 2 commits.

Comment: Now what if 2B and 2C where nested queries? Something like: 
UPDATE seats SET count = (SELECT count FROM seats WHERE user_id = 1) + 1 WHERE user_id = 1 
I am not sure if this is a valid query or not, but wanted to ask just for understanding purpose

Comment: MySQL complains if you try to SELECT from the same table that you are UPDATEing, but you could do `UPDATE seats SET count = count + 1 WHERE user_id = 1`. That would act like a locking query, and it would use the most current committed version of the row.

Comment: I've had postgres queries that does SELECT on same table, infact same row which its updating

Answer (score -1):

The answer is... it depends. Since you tagged MySQL I assume you are using that DBMS. But which engine? Let's assume InnoDB.

Are you explicitly starting transactions? If you don't, InnoDB by default will be in `autocommit` mode (unless you reset it). This means that each statement will be a transaction in itself, so the sequence 2B - 1A - 2C will show the "wrong" behaviour.

If you explicitly include 2B and 2C in a transaction, it still depends on the isolation level. The default isolation level of InnoDB, REPEATABLE READ, will prevent the "wrong" behaviour, and the same holds true for SERIALIZABLE (the most conservative level); but the two more optimistic levels, READ COMMITTED and READ UNCOMMITTED, won't.

Comment: Understood. Now what if 2B and 2C where nested queries? Something like: UPDATE seats SET count = (SELECT count FROM seats WHERE user_id = 1) + 1 WHERE user_id = 1 I am not sure if this is a valid query or not, but wanted to ask just for understanding purpose –

Comment: A nested query would be a single transaction even if you didn't explicitly manage it. So all the default settings are ok in this case

Comment: Then there is no need to explicitly have a write-lock in the inner query? -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66006278/are-nested-sql-queries-atomic

Comment: Speaking of MySQL, InnoDB, default settings I would say there's no need to make explicit locks (let's ignore that MySQL won't perform a SELECT and an UPDATE on the same table). Other systems/engines may behave differently, you need to check the specific documentation (and probably run some tests)